# postgreSQL: How to use ROLE to allow full access to all users part of a given role (without using SET ROLE prior accessing a table for instance)

Tags: postgresql, roles

I'm coming to postgreSQL with a SQL Server background and was naively applying the same concepts to postgreSQL in order to allow different users to share 'by default' some objects within a database.

This is what I did:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
CREATE ROLE testdb_role_full INHERIT;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO testdb_role_full;

CREATE USER user1 INHERIT; 
GRANT testdb_role_full TO user1;

CREATE USER user2 INHERIT; 
GRANT testdb_role_full TO user2;
```

Once done, I created a table t1 using the user1.
Then, I tried, as user2, to read the t1 table and I received a "permission denied error"... :-(

By reading the documentation, it seems that I have to issue a `SET ROLE testdb_role_full` first so as to act as the testdb_role_full.

However, this is not really that I want. I do not want the user to be aware of this.

So my question:

Is there any way to make this work?

Thanks a lot,
José

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've granted some privileges on the database, but that doesn't mean any user with the role `testdb_role_full` would have all privileges on all objects inside that database. To quote from [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-priv.html):

> When an object is created, it is assigned an owner. The owner is normally the role that executed the creation statement. For most kinds of objects, the initial state is that only the owner (or a superuser) can do anything with the object. To allow other roles to use it, privileges must be granted.

So after the `user1` created the table `t1`, he is the owner and only he has the privileges on it. He would need to run

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE t1 TO testdb_role_full;
```

then `user2` would be able to access it as well (without having to switch any roles - that's only necessary when it has the `NOINHERIT` attribute on the role).

---

If you don't want your users to have to execute `GRANT` each time they create a new object in the database, you can [alter the default privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) that will be applied whenever an object is created by `user2`:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR user2
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO testdb_role_full;
```

Notice these specify the initial value only, and `user2` could revoke the privileges on his tables if he wanted to prevent others from seeing them.

Comment: Concerning "full access": it might be worth noting that you cannot grant another user the right to `ALTER` or `DROP` an object you own.

Comment: Thanks!
It works great. Just for completion, we should apply the `ALTER DEFAULT ....` within the context of user2. Otherwise, it does not work.

Comment: @Jose I think `FOR user2` is enough - but you might need the respective privileges to do that, i.e. be able to assume the `user2` role or being a superuser.